# How to validate if a SharePoint group already has permission on the site using Client Object Model?

Tags: 2013, permissions, client-object-model

I'd like to check if a certain group already has permission on the site using the client object model.

I couldn't find any good example for that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl"); 
GroupCollection collGroup = clientContext.Web.SiteGroups;
clientContext.Load(collGroup);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
Group newGrp = collGroup.Where(g => g.Title == "TitleOfGroup").FirstOrDefault();
if (newGrp != null)
{
    // Add new group logic
}
```